# WCF DataContractJsonSerializer - Exclude specific properties at runtime

Tags: wcf, json, serialization

I am serializing a .net 4 object using DataContractJsonSerializer.  How can I include/exclude specific properties from serialization based on information only available at runtime ?   Can the IDataContractSurrogate be used for this ?  If so....I need a good sample.  I primarily want to exclude properties.   I do NOT want to substitute nulls....however I want to exclude specific properties entirely at runtime.   I want to do at runtime which is the equivalent of removing DataMember attribute at pre-runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

He asked the same question and got a very good response at the following link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/dd520d9b-334f-4e78-9b08-bf809b887e4f